# Where to store boxes/cases of Carbonated Energy Drinks (Like Red Bull) Fridge or Room?

Tags: storage-method, temperature, drinks, carbonation

I hope this is the right place to ask this. And sorry for the bad english. I didn't know whether "box" is right for what I have or "case", or "pack" !

I'm a self-admitted Energy Drink junkie! So I thought I should buy boxes of them to save money, because the stores in my town sell them in a higher-than-usual price of the distributor! (Some even sell them twice the actual price!) So now I've bought Two boxes of 24packed 250ml cans (48 cans). And for several reasons I don't want to/can't store all the cans in the fridge, most important of which; don't have enought space in the fridge to store all of these in.

I keep my room chilly because basicly I just like it~! (Unlike my family! :D) I don't have a thermometer or I would have just told you the room temperature. The outside temperature is about 12C to -4C (decreases to 7C and lower and lower after 6PM, then increases again after 8AM...) And I keep my window a little bit open (Like 30%) all the time...

So based on this explanations, What would you suggest? Will they lose fizziness or go flat if they aren't kept in fridge? ... I'm sure you've understood what I mean by now :) if not, please tell me to make myself more clear. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Storage? Doesn't matter so much so long as the drinks are not subjected to broad temperature swings. Put them in the fridge at least 24 hours before you want to drink them so they can get chilled nicely.